# 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'as_independent'

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm new to python. I am trying to run this code but this error message appears : 'ImmutableDenseNDimArray' object has no attribute 'could_extract_minus_sign'

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)
simx=np.random.normal(loc=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 2, 1), size=(1000,3)) 
simx=np.matrix(simx)                                                 
matx = np.hstack(( np.ones((1000, 1)), simx[:, 0:2] ))               

beta0, beta1, beta2 = 1, 2, 0.5
y = beta0*matx[:,0] + beta1*matx[:,1] + beta2*matx[:,2] + simx[:,2] 

a, b, c = sp.symbols('a, b, c')
residual=y-a*matx[:,0] - b*matx[:,1] - c*matx[:,2]
epsilon=residual.T@residual
da=sp.diff(epsilon[0],a)
db=sp.diff(epsilon[0],b)
dc=sp.diff(epsilon[0],c)
sp.solve([da, db, dc])
```

Pls help! thanks so much.

Comment: Please provide your error log in the question

Comment: Don't use `numpy` and `sympy` together - unless you really know what you  are doing.  Often `sympy.lambdify` is the only useful means of integrating them.  Use `sympy's` own matrix modules, or lists.  If you want more help show the full error message (traceback), and the relevant variables or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When constructing `simx` you use `np.matrix`.  The result is that all following arrays are also `np.matrix`.  If you read the `np.matrix` docs, you'll see that the class is discouraged if not actually deprecated.

In an `isympy` session, your code produces:

```
In [22]: type(epsilon)
Out[22]: numpy.matrix

In [23]: epsilon.dtype, epsilon.shape
Out[23]: (dtype('O'), (1, 1))

In [24]: epsilon[0].dtype, epsilon[0].shape
Out[24]: (dtype('O'), (1, 1))
```

Because of the `np.matrix` class `epsilon[0]` does nothing for you.

You have to use the full 2d indexing if you want to extract the sympy element from that matrix:

```
In [25]: type(epsilon[0,0])
Out[25]: sympy.core.add.Add
```

Look  at what happens when you try to apply `sympy.diff` to the matrix, as opposed to the `Add`:

```
In [26]: type(diff(epsilon[0],a))
Out[26]: sympy.tensor.array.dense_ndim_array.ImmutableDenseNDimArray

In [27]: type(diff(epsilon[0,0],a))
Out[27]: sympy.core.add.Add
```

In [26] `diff` has converted the `np.matrix` into a `sympy` array object.  Apparently the `sympy.solve` has problems working with that.  It might be ok with the `diff` produced as in [27].

As I commented, mixing `numpy` and `sympy` is not for the beginner.  Your use of `np.matrix` (as opposed to `np.array`) only made things more complicated for you.

When debugging pay real attention to the error message, including the traceback.  We usually expect you to show it in full, though in this case you have provided enough code to reproduce the problem.  Also examine variables along the way - as I've done with `epsilon`.

===

```
In [28]: da=diff(epsilon[0,0],a)
    ...: db=diff(epsilon[0,0],b)
    ...: dc=diff(epsilon[0,0],c)

In [29]: foo = solve([da,db,dc])

In [30]: foo
Out[30]: {a: 1.0137595332538, b: 2.00366875358228, c: 0.491065343898908}
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!